# TimeZone: get the abbreviation instead of the GMT offset

Tags: ios, date, timezone, nsdate, nstimezone

I need to get the abbreviation of the timezone.

For example, Moscow, Russia has the abbreviation `MSK`. Central European Time has the abbreviation of `CET`, Eastern European Summer Time has `EEST`, etc.

When I open the macOS settings, I can see the abbreviation clearly:

[image: macos settings screenshot]

However, when I try to get the abbreviation in code, I get only the `GMT` offset:

```
import UIKit
let date = Date()
let zone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EEST")
print(zone?.abbreviation(for: Date()))
```

> Optional("GMT+3")

On the other hand, when I try to use the US time, I get the correct abbreviation:

```
import UIKit
let date = Date()
let zone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EDT")
print(zone?.abbreviation(for: Date()))
```

> Optional("EDT")

**How can I always enforce `TimeZone` to give the abbreviation instead of the GMT offset? Are there any other way to always get the abbreviation, regardless of the locale, or other system settings?**

My goal is to get the same string as in the macOS settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've play with snippet code. Hope that helps you solve your problem.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

public struct LocalTime {
    var timeZone: TimeZone?
    var dateTime: String
    init(timeZone: TimeZone, dateTime: String) {
        self.timeZone = timeZone
        self.dateTime = dateTime
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timeZone: TimeZone?
    var localTime: LocalTime?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.getLocalTimeZone(lat: 47.6062, lon: -122.3321, dateTime: "2017-06-10T00:30:00Z")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }

    func convertToLocalDateFromUTCDate(dateStr: String) -> String {
        let utcDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        utcDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        let sourceDate = utcDateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
        let localDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        localDateFormatter.timeZone = self.timeZone
        localDateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:'00'"
        guard let date = sourceDate else { return "" }
        let localTime = localDateFormatter.string(from: date)
        return localTime
    }

    func getLocalTimeZone(lat: Double, lon: Double, dateTime: String) {
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        var dateTimeString: String?
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { [weak self] (placemarks, err) in
            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                guard let self = self else { return }
                dateTimeString = self.convertToLocalDateFromUTCDate(dateStr: dateTime)
                guard let timeZone = placemark.timeZone, let dateTimeString = dateTimeString else { return }
                self.localTime = LocalTime(timeZone: timeZone, dateTime: dateTimeString)
                debugPrint("\(self.localTime?.timeZone?.abbreviation())")
                debugPrint("\(self.localTime?.dateTime)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
"Optional(\"PDT\")"
"Optional(\"10-06-2017 07:30:00\")"
```